# Regex using lookahead or lookbehind

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to solve a problem of matching part of the string using regex.

So for eg if my

```
bigString = 'I am going to school. Which one, said one of the friend. Well, I dont know but it is owned by Beats Ltd., and I kind of like it and our principal K.L.Doubies is extremely good. I cant imagine going to any other school.'
```

If I want to extract a part of string which starts with a dot but doesn't contain a dot after at least 2 character and contains 'principal' word. In short I need a complete sentence. So in my `bigString` I would like to match -- `''. Well, I dont know but it is owned by Beats Ltd., and I kind of like it and our principal K.L.Doubies is extremely good.''`

Here is my attempt:

```
r'\.((?!\w\w+\.).)*principal.*?\w\w+\.'
```

In my lookahead `(?!\w\w+\.)` I would ideally like to use exceptions to ignore words like Ltd. Co. Dr.

Comment: How do you determine the end of a sentence? Eg if "K.L.Doubies" was actually "K. L. Doubies", it would be pretty difficult to differentiate - or do sentences always end with `\.($| )`, and periods inside sentences are never followed by spaces?

Comment: Would `(?<=\. )[a-zA-Z ,.]*principal[a-zA-Z ,.]*\.(?= [A-Z])` [work](https://regex101.com/r/B5T8EG/2) ? CertainPerformance does make a good point.

Comment: sentences generally end with dot (which is usually preceeded by \w+. If it is K. L. Doubies - I will assume that sentences dont end with a single capital letter and then a dot.

Comment: The best idea is to use some NLP package to split the paragraph into senences, and then filter to get the one having `principal`. Regex is not language grammar/syntax aware.